# How to use subclasses of an abstract class as a parameter of a method?

Tags: java, abstract-class

I am looking for an efficient way to initiate objects of different class with one method. The object that the method initiate is not the same each time. All the object that the method initializes inherits from the same abstract class.

For exemple, we have a chess game. We have an abstract class ( for this exemple, we will name it AbstractPiece )for the overall functioning of the pieces and each piece in the game (king, queen, rook, etc.) has a class which inherits from the abstract class. We also have a class that manages the game. This class has a method that initiates the pieces of the game, which receives as parameters the color, position and type of piece that it must initialize. Since each part has a diferent class, the method must therefore initialize the object using the constructor of the part we want to initialize. The method should look something like that.

```
public void initPiece(Position position, Color color, AbstractPiece typeOfThePieceWeWantToInitialise){
    AbstractPiece piece = new typeOfThePieceWeWantToInitialise(color, position);
}
```

This sample of code is not working but what a want to achieve is similar to this situation. Any idea on how to make something working that achieve the same thing that the code sample above ( if it would work )?

Comment: You can not instantiate an Abstract class - what are you trying to do?

Comment: Your question may in fact be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask "how do I fix this code problem" when the best solution is to use a different approach entirely. Consider telling us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you don't care for the sub-classes to have methods that the abstract class doesn't (i'e just overriding the abstract classes methods).

believe the solution you are looking for may be something as simple as:

```
public AbCLass initiate(int type, param one, param two)
{
   switch(type)
   {
      case 1:
      return new SubOne(one, two);
      break;
      case 2:
      return new SubTwo(one, two);
      break;
      ...
      default:
      return null;
   }
}
```

a Class object doesn't represent a class per se, it is its own class which acts as a description of the class.